# A normed space of continuous functions with norm $\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt$ is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Suppose $E$ is a normed space of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with norm $\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt$. Prove that $E$ is not complete

I know that we must do is to find a Cauchy sequence of continous functions that doesn't converge in $E$, but I can't find that sequence. Can any one help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$f_n=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}\> 0\le x<1/2\\
n(x-1/2) & \text{if}\> 1/2\le x < 1/2 + 1/n\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then each $f_n$ is continuous and $\langle f_n\rangle$ is Cauchy but it does not converge at any continuous function.

Comment: Very clever choice. Thanks so much tetori